# Why this reverse string logic in java wont work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please explain why this logic wont work in python. But works in java?

```
def reverse(number):
reversedNumber = 0;
temp = 0;

while(number > 0):
    #use modulus operator to strip off the last digit
    temp = number%10;
    print(temp) #4
    #create the reversed number
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + temp;
    number = number/10;
    print("reversedNumber", reversedNumber)
```

reverse(1234)

Comment: Where's java code? And whats wrong with above code?

Comment: *How* does it not work? What result do you get? Also, I'm not familiar with php, but have you tried `number = (number - temp) / 10` so you're sure the value is integer? I ask because I don't know what the result of `1234/10` is (in php).

Comment: works in ideone: http://ideone.com/qouUdl (with changing // to #)

Comment: Ok, either post the java code or write what output are you expecting. Right now, it reverses the number, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: It's just that the comments are wrong. Comments start with `#` in python, not `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 dividing two integers can return a float. In most languages `1/2 == 0`. In Python 3 `1/2 == 0.5`. To get integer division in python three you use a double division sign, i.e. `1//2 == 0`.

Note, this is a difference between Python 2 and 3.

Also does not work because comments in Python are written starting with a `#` not `//`.

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear it. Since this answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as your accepted answer by clicking the check mark?